# How to add a NavigationLink inline between 2 Text

Tags: swiftui

I want to have a NavigationLink in between 2 Text elements in SwiftUI. Concatenating them together isn't working since Swift apparently only accepts concatenating elements of the same type.

**Example**

Expected outcome: Read our [Terms & Conditions](http://example.com/terms) to learn more.

What I've tried:

```swift
Text("Read our ") + NavigationLink("Terms & Conditions") { TermsPage() } + Text(" to learn more.")
```

The error I got

> Cannot convert value of type 'NavigationLink<Label, TermsPage>' to expected argument type 'Text'

I know that you can embed links in Markdown format

```
Text("Read our [Terms & Conditions](example.com/terms) to learn more.")
```

But that will open a webpage which isn't the desired behavior. I have a page inside the app that I want to navigate into. I just need the link to be inline with the text.

Comment: You can’t you have to use markdown along with the other tools to open views. The code for the “widget code along” has a decent sample it is geared for widgets but the concept is very similar with markdown

Comment: @loremipsum How to use markdown to open views? That's what I'm trying to do, but the url you pass in the markdown cannot open views.

Comment: You can open views programmatically by intercepting the click. Look in SO this exact question has been asked several times lately, but like I said the widget code along code uses it to open detail views for the individual characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something simple like this approach using a `HStack`:

```
   @State var showTerms = false
   //....

    NavigationStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Read our")
            Text("Terms & Conditions").foregroundColor(.blue)
                .onTapGesture { showTerms = true }
            Text("to learn more.")
        }.fixedSize()
        NavigationLink("", destination: TermsPage(), isActive: $showTerms)
    }
```